# String conversion in matlab doesn't work with int values

Tags: matlab, parsing, string-conversion

I'm parsing longstrings in matlab and whenever I use str2num with an int it doesn't work, it outputs a weird Chinese or Greek symbol instead.

```
satrec.satnum = str2num(longstr1(3:7));
```

I checked by outputting it as a string, it works properly but I won't be able to use it in my calculations later on if I don't manage to change it to an int. The characters 3 to 7 of my string are ints (ex : 8188). As it appears to work if my strings are doubles, I tried this :

```
satrec.satnum = longstr1(3:7);  
satrec.satnum = strcat(satrec.satnum,'.0');
satrec.satnum = str2num(satrec.satnum);
fprintf('satellite number : %s\n',satrec.satnum);
```

But it outputs the same weird symbol. Does anyone know what I can do ?

Comment: what does `longstr1` look like?

Comment: Like this :
'1 28895U 05043F   14195.24580016  .00000503  00000-0  10925-3 0  8188'

Comment: Are you reading this from a file? Is the file possibly in some weird encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like NORAD 2-line element data. In that case the file encoding is US-ASCII or effectively UTF-8 since no non-ASCII characters should be present.

Your problem appears to be in this line:

```
fprintf('satellite number : %s\n',satrec.satnum);
```

satrec.satnum is an integer, but you are printing it with a %s character in the format string, so Matlab is interpreting it as a string. Replace this with

```
fprintf('satellite number : %d\n',satrec.satnum);
```

and you get the correct result.

**Edited to add**

Matlab has in fact converted the string to an int correctly!

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the the code you provided along with your example, and am unable to reproduce the problem you described:

```
longstr1='1 28895U 05043F 14195.24580016 .00000503 00000-0 10925-3 0 8188';
satrec.satnum = str2num(longstr1(3:7))

satrec = 

    satnum: 28895
```

In any case, I'd suggest using something like `textscan` or `dlmread`:

```
Data = textscan(longstr1,'%u8 %u16 %c %u16 %c %f %f %u16-%u8 %u16-%u8 %u8 %u16', 'delimiter', '')

Data = 

  Columns 1 through 9

    [1]    [28895]    'U'    [5043]    'F'    [1.4195e+04]    [5.0300e-06]    [0]    [0]

  Columns 10 through 13

    [10925]    [3]    [0]    [8188]
```

In the above example I guessed some of the data-types so you should update them for your use. 
As you can see, this code works on a string. If however you provide it with fileID it will read all the lines in the file ([see documentation for textscan](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html)) using this template.

**On a side note**: I noticed that `char(28895)` outputs a Chinese character.